# Implement animation during Vue first loading time

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, single-page-application

I am going to add an animation during the application's modules' first loading time. 
I can add an image but can't add an animation to the image. 
I tried to include a CSS file but it doesn't work sometimes. 
So I tried to add an SVG image and insert `animateTransform` to the SVG element. 
But it also doesn't work. 
Is there any good idea to add an animation to the image?

Here is my body code of index.html file.

```
<body>
<noscript>
  <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript>
<div id="app">
  <div id="loading__container">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      viewBox="0 0 86.03 67.01"
      class="img-logo"
      style="position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);width: 100px;">
      <defs>
        ...
      </defs>
      <g class="cls-1">
        <animateTransform
          attributeName="transform"
          attributeType="XML"
          type="scale"
          additive="sum"
          keyTimes="0;0.5;1"
          values="0.5;1;0.5"
          dur="1s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"/>
          <g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2">
            ...
          </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
```

Comment: Please include the basic code you have tried.

Comment: Hi @AHaworth! 
I added my body code in my question.
Please have a check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with myself.
I used the image element instead of svg element.
Here is the code

```
<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <div id="loading__container">
    <img src="<%= BASE_URL %>initial_img.png" alt="initial loading">
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the style that I inserted into

```
<style>
  @keyframes zoom-in-zoom-out {
    0% {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
    50% {
      transform: scale(1.5, 1.5);
    }
    100% {
      transform: scale(1, 1);
    }
  }
  #loading__container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  #loading__container img{
    animation: zoom-in-zoom-out 1s ease-in infinite;
  }
</style>
```